# Test Class on Approval Action Apex Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, approval-process, invocable-method

I have an Invocable apex class for approval actions.  I am trying to get test coverage on this.  But I must be missing something as there are no lines of code coverage.  I am new to apex so its probably something simple that I am missing.

Apex Class:

```
global class approvalAction
{
   @InvocableMethod
    Public static void recallApproval(List<Request> requests) 
        
    {   
        If (requests[0].varActionType == 'Reassign') {
           
            ProcessInstanceWorkItem pi = [SELECT Id, ActorId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkItem WHERE ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId =: requests[0].recId];
            pi.ActorId = requests[0].varReassign;
            update pi;
                       
        }
            
        else{
            
        List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> piwi = [SELECT Id, ProcessInstanceId, ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem WHERE ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId =: requests[0].recId];
        Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
        req.setAction(requests[0].varActionType);       
        req.setWorkitemId(piwi.get(0).Id);
        req.setComments(requests[0].varComments);
   
        Approval.process(req,false);
    }
        }
    
    public class InvocableErrorException extends Exception{}
    
    Public Class Request {
        @invocableVariable
        public Id recId;
        @InvocableVariable
        public string varComments;
        @invocableVariable
        public string varActionType;
        @invocableVariable
        Public Id varReassign;
    }
    public class Response {
     
       @invocableVariable
        public Boolean isSuccess; 
        
        @invocableVariable
        public String errors;

    }
    public class InvocableActionException extends Exception {}
}
```

My Test class is:

```
@isTest
public class approvalActionTest {

    @isTest
    public static void CanChangeApprovalAction () {
        
        //create record
        String gsRecordTypeID = Schema.SObjectType.IT_Intake__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('ET VHA').getRecordTypeId();
        It_Intake__c TestIntake1 = new IT_Intake__c();
        TestIntake1.Short_Description_of_your_Request__c = 'Testing Intake 1';
        TestIntake1.Status__c = 'Pending Review';
        TestIntake1.RecordTypeId = gsRecordTypeID;
        Insert TestIntake1;
      
        //Submit for Approval
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest testapproval = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        testapproval.setComments('Submitting request for approval');
        testapproval.setObjectId(TestIntake1.Id);
        //testapproval.setObjectId('a5Er0000000CebJEAS');
        Approval.ProcessResult result1 = Approval.process(testapproval);
        
        //call approvalAction
        
        approvalAction.Request testApp = new approvalAction.Request();
        testApp.recId = TestIntake1.Id;
        //testApp.recId = 'a5Er0000000CebJEAS';
        testApp.varActionType = 'Approve';
        testApp.varComments = 'Good to go';
        
        List<approvalAction.Request> regAppList = new List<approvalAction.Request>();
        regAppList.add(testApp);               
        
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to call `approvalAction.recallApproval` in your test class, otherwise you're not going to cover any of the code in that method.